# Let the duplicate questions finder consider tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, similar-questions

When asking a new question and typing in the title we get a list of similar questions named

> Questions that may already have your answer

[image: Question Finder]

That suggestions contains posts across all tags. Like the example in the screenshot it returns similar questions for Python, jQuery, SQL, C#, Java, C++, ...

This makes the list less useless unlikely people find a question that already answers theirs. If people actually find a similar question in that list many duplicates could be avoided.

So can tags I entered below the question be considered to update the list? And can the tag textbox maybe put above the question title?

Comment: One thing that might be an counterproductive is if you use say [java] [string] [integer] (and assuming the list only includes questions which match all the tags) you will probably lose a lot of questions which have been asked with the [java] tag only.

Comment: I don't think that would be a big problem since tags are added normally after writing the topic. And if you not, the asker is probably a more experienced user who knows about tags.

Comment: Some related posts on Meta Stack Overflow: [Questions that definitely do not have the answer to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360337) and [Duplicate questions display experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384710). (Both of them are from 2019 - so they are relatively recent.)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that moving the 'tags' line below the question title, above the suggested possible duplicates, and using the tags information would be helpful.

It also might help to reduce the number of users placing tags in their title, as they see right next to the title that they are tagging their question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "wizard" type GUI mechanism for new user questions (or rep < n) might serve a number of purposes: avoiding duplicates, improving questions, improving formatting. While I'm no great fan of "wizards" used haphazardly, there is a place for sequenced user-input collection devices for new users.