# Suggestions when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, new-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enhance questions finder if asking a new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137981/enhance-questions-finder-if-asking-a-new-one)

Proposal I would like to make concerns the suggestions we get when we are asking a question on a specific tag.

The problem is that the propositions we get are not referred to this specific tag.
So there should be filter on the suggestions according to the tag we are interested in.

I am talking about the pop-up and sidebar lists of possible duplicates when composing a question. I want for example to ask how we extract a subdirectory from a path in language R. I enter the title of my question and I instantly get some proposistions but they refer to any software available and not specifically to the tag of R.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

I intended to ask my question about ASP.NET, and in fact (consider the 4th suggestion) some of the suggestion lead me to nowhere and opening each of them is a time consuming process.  Please filter the suggestions based on (I'm not sure what it should really be):

- Tags entered in tags text box
- Tags of my interest (remove my filter-out tags)
- Show the questions' tag(s) when hovering with the mouse

Comment: What propositions are you talking about? An example would be most welcome.

Comment: @Oded: The pop-up and sidebar lists of possible duplicates when composing a question. (I believe.)

Comment: Josh Caswell is right. I want for example to ask how we extract a subdirectory from a path in language R. I enter the title of my question and I instantly get some proposistions but they refer to any software available and not specifically to the tag of R.

Comment: There are no tags in the title for the "proposer" to filter on.

Comment: I would have said that it's because at the time of writing the title, the asker has not yet specified the tags ... However after testing it this doesn't seem to have an impact...

Comment: @ Lix: The impact is that the volume of the proposals is quite large for the user to check all of them. So it is most probable to dublicate a question.

Comment: I second this proposal. However, note that (for you, the seasoned veteran) you can work around this problem by placing the words you're going to use as your tags in the question title. If you don't find a duplicate, remove them and then move them to the tags line. :/

Comment: +1. It's pointless getting suggestions on how to do it in Java when you need to do it with Python.  All those irrelevant questions just lead to clutter which leads to ignoring it which leads to duplicates which leads to LMGTFY anger management!

Comment: @Oded I added a screenshot that explains what the OP (and I) means.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but too lazy to prove it :) Note that the logical extension of this feature-request would be to put the tag edit box directly after the title, before the question body.